# Running different programs via ssh

Tags: shell, script, ssh, jvm

I got some problem when I tried to run different programs via SSH.

The problem is, let's say I have 2 different java programs, then I would like to run them simultaneously on different JVM, in order to do this, I wrote a shell script to launch those 2 programs, when I tried on my local machine, it works fine, because I used command of      gnome-terminal, so you can see tow terminals pop up and each of them has a single program to run but, when I use SSH to connect to a remote machine, I run the same program, some weird things happen, the terminals pop up one by one rather than pop up simultaneously, so those 2 programs don't run at the same time, but run first followed by another.

Is there any idea why this gonna happen?

I use

> gnome-terminal -e "java myclass"

to launch the program

I use

> ./myscript.sh params

to launch the shell script

I use

> ssh -X user@server

to connect to the remote server

Comment: are you asking how to run two simultaneous programs in a single ssh session? It can be done with `screen`

Comment: Maybe, running first program asyncronously (`java-1.6-v1 Main1 &
java-1.7-v2 Main2`) can help?